# Is this json badly constructed?

Tags: json, api, parsing, schema, jsonschema

The following json text is the result of a call to eBay's search API.

#### Q: [Is this json](https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/9496538) badly constructed? (It's technically, correct - so that's not what I'm referring to)

By that I mean, notice how -every value- is inside an array? instead of just being a `"key" : "value"` ?

eg.

```
"ack": [
        "Success"
      ],
```

or

```
"version": [
        "1.12.0"
      ],
```

etc..

Now, before you answer "*well, maybe each key has multiple result values*" .. I'm pretty sure *most* of them can't.

(this json schema is really making my life a pita. yes, it's easy to make each POCO property a `List<string>` but it's the point of it all!)

References: [Here's the office eBay API documention for this endpoint](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation, I understand eBay's approach, but I find it poor in terms of client side deserialisation. For example, the benefit of an array value for the `ack` property is that the value could also contain a warning, e.g.:

```
{
    "ack": [
        "Success",
        "Warning"
    ]
}
```

However, a list of strings is not ideal for client side processing (e.g. in C#, `bool hasWarning = pocoList.Contains("Warning");` doesn't strike me as completely foolproof). I'd rather have a response such as:

```
{
    "ack": {
        "result": "Success",
        "warning": null
    }
}
```

Then with my deserialised POCO, given that the value of `warning` is still a string, I could write this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Ack
{
    [DataMember(Name="result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="warning")]
    public string Warning { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool HasWarning
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Warning); }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to replace my previous LINQ query with `bool hasWarning = ack.HasWarning;`.

There are definitely places where use of arrays is completely unnecessary. The docs describe the `version` property as "the release version that eBay used to process the request", thus I would return this as a single string. The array would only make sense if it was a `versions` property (e.g. for identifying all versions of the backend that support a specific request).

I've definitely seen worse JSON responses, but there are places where the APIs should ideally be returning a JSON object or a single value.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this tool for see if a JSON is good constructed:

http://json.parser.online.fr/

In your case, is not correct. You should store the data by Keys and Values.